# direct output of variable and through print() are different

Tags: python

Suppose I have string

```
S = '\\\\Serial\\file'
```

Output:

```
S

'\\\\Serial\\file'


print(s)

\\Serial\file
```

So the question is what is the reason print function truncate the backslashes ?

But still why it remove two backslashes from front and just one from last? what could be the reason? and why its removing?

Also it dont gives ' ' is that any meaning or use?

Comment: A backslash is used to define special characters, like \n meaning new line. So in order to have a "regular" backslash you have to define it with another backslash.

Comment: If you want to have the "raw" string you can indicate it like this in python: `S = r'\\\\Serial\\file'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a python string `\` is a character which is combined with another character is order to define a special character.

For example, the string `\n` represents a new line, instead of the actual backslash n. So why is this important? Because then to indicate a backslash you actually need two backslashes. The first one indicates the special string and the second indicates the actual backslash. Therefore every two backslashes is one backslash when printed. That's why the first four backslashes become two (4/2 = 2) and the second ones become one (2/2 = 1). If you want to indicate the raw string, you can indicate it with an r, i.e.

`s = r"\\test"`

which will print as typed.

As for the missing ', those just indicate the beginning or end of a string, when printing, everything is converted to a string and the ' are omitted.